# Any faster way to search each value of one column through another column in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, search, iteration

I need to search through each value of a column, do some comparison with all entries of another column and, if certain conditions are met, print. I'm using the python code below and it works, but the drawback is that both columns have tens of thousands of entries, so it's very slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
for i in df1.index:
    for j in df2['pdb']:
        if df1['pdb'][i] == df2['pdb'][j]:
            if df1['res1'][i] >= df2['start'][j] and df1['res2'][i] <= df2['end'][j]: 
                print(df1['pdb'][i], df2['PFAM_ACC'][j])
```

Example:

```
df1 = 
pdb    res1   res2
4xhfA   76    83
4xhfA   126   133
2mx1A   179   186
3s8lA   111   118
4ucmA   115   122
1pigA   119   126
4mavA   263   270
4mavA   289   296
3sbrA   101   108
3sbrA   148   155
3sbrA   158   165
3sbrA   222   229
3sbrA   394   401
5zeaA   83    90
5zeaC   562   569
5zeaD   32    39
5zeaD   89    96
5zeaG   277   284

df2 =
 pdb    start  end  PFAM_ACC
 4xhfA  140    236  PF04205
 1pigA  61     332  PF00128
 1pigA  409    493  PF02806
 3sbrA  171    241  PF18793
 3sbrA  424    494  PF18764
 3sbrA  558    635  PF00116
 5zeaA  13     75   PF02874
 5zeaC  13     75   PF02874
 5zeaD  15     81   PF02874
 5zeaG  13     75   PF02874
```

and I want to get as output:

```
 1pigA     PF00128
 3sbrA     PF18793
 5zeaD     PF02874
```

I hope it's more clear now.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output (in text form - so we can copy-and-paste it)?

Comment: Thanks Andrej, I have edited it. I hope it's now clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x = df1.merge(df2, on="pdb")
out = x.loc[
    (x["res1"] >= x["start"]) & (x["res2"] <= x["end"]), ["pdb", "PFAM_ACC"]
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
      pdb PFAM_ACC
2   1pigA  PF00128
13  3sbrA  PF18793
21  5zeaD  PF02874
```

Comment: Fantastic! much much faster. Thanks a lot!